# Delete a record from a Tstring Grid and a dataFile

Tags: delphi

How can I pass a selected row in a Tstring grid to this deleteFromfile procedure. The first two procedures enable me to delete a selected row in a Tstring grid. Therefore deleting a record from a TString Grid.However the records are stored within a file. I need to delete the record from the file aswell as delete the record from the Tstring grid.

```
procedure DeleteCurrentRow(Grid: TStringGrid);
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      for i := Grid.Row to Grid.RowCount - 2 do
        Grid.Rows[i].Assign(Grid.Rows[i + 1]);
      Grid.RowCount := Grid.RowCount - 1;
    end;


    procedure TManageUsersForm.RemoveUserButtonClick(Sender: TObject);

    begin
      UserStringGrid.Options := UserStringGrid.Options + [goEditing];
      UserStringGrid.Options := UserStringGrid.Options + [goRowSelect];
      DeleteCurrentRow(UserStringGrid);
    end;

procedure DeleteFromfile();
begin
  if messagedlg('Are you sure you want to Delete this record?',
  mtconfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes
  then
    begin
      reset (UserFile);
      seek (UserFile, FileSize(UserFile) –1);
      read (UserFile, User);
      seek (UserFile, recordposition);
      write (UserFile, User);
      seek (UserFile, FileSize(UserFile) –1);
      truncate (UserFile);
      closefile (UserFile);
    end
  {endif}
end;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Why did you choose legacy Pascal IO? What happens when there are no rows? That modification to RowCount will be a problem.

Comment: You seem to be working backwards. A `TStringGrid` is not a place for you to store data in your application, it's only a user control to display and control your underlying data. That being said, you should delete your record from your file first, then update your grid to reflect this change.

Comment: How will can I pass the selected row to the deletefromfile procedure.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm. Im not sure what the parameter would be :(

Comment: Pass the index of the row. Do you know about parameters yet?